# How to convert milliseconds to date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data look like this ( `/Date(1500921000000)/` ) and I want to convert into Date. How IDK. help me, please

Comment: What does your data looks like, is it string?

Comment: For miliseconds to readable date / time string, I am using momentjs.org - for eample: moment(1500921000000).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') will return string like this: July 29th 2017, 1:05:28 pm

Comment: In JS `new Date(1500921000000)` already gives you the according date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
//DEFINE THE FUNCTION TO GET DATE FROM MILISECOND
var format = function (time, format) {
            var t = new Date(time);
            var tf = function (i) { return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i };
            return format.replace(/yyyy|MM|dd|HH|mm|ss/g, function (a) {
                switch (a) {
                    case 'yyyy':
                        return tf(t.getFullYear());
                        break;
                    case 'MM':
                        return tf(t.getMonth() + 1);
                        break;
                    case 'mm':
                        return tf(t.getMinutes());
                        break;
                    case 'dd':
                        return tf(t.getDate());
                        break;
                    case 'HH':
                        return tf(t.getHours());
                        break;
                    case 'ss':
                        return tf(t.getSeconds());
                        break;
                }
            })
        }

//ALERT  THE OUTPUT OF "1500921000000" MILISECOND 
alert(format(new Date(1500921000000).getTime(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
```

try that then let me know the result, Thanks